# can't insert data in sqlite table in ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 1. I connected my app with sqlite. I want to see the table data that are inserted. And display the inserted data in the console. But, I can't figure out Why row length is still 0. And there is no error on console. Here's my controller code snippet:

```
.controller('salesCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$cordovaSQLite',  // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName

function ($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaSQLite) {
    var db=null;

      if (window.cordova) {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "pos.db" }); //device
     console.log("not in browser");
    }else{
      db = window.openDatabase("pos.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      console.log("browser");

    }
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,firstname text  NOT NULL,lastname text  NOT NULL)");
           $scope.insert=function(){
                    var query="INSERT into items(firstname,lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,["name1","name2"]).then(function(result){

                        console.log(result.rows);
                    },function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                    })


                }

}])
```

and here is my template page code snippet in which when someone click the button it will call the `insert()` function.

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-left" id="sales-list-item4" ui-sref="menu.itemQuantity">
        <i class="icon ion-android-checkbox-blank"></i>
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-cart-outline" ng-click="insert()"> click</button>
        <span class="item-note">600  </span>
      </ion-item>
```

Comment: result.rows return for select statement, in case of the insert statement ionic return the inserted object, thus console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);

Comment: @digit What if I want to see the values that are inserted.

Comment: You could console.log whole object by console.log('object:', result)

Comment: Yes, that I know I can, But, even if I have inserted data. I can't see any data in the object. Not even the name of my table. @digit

Comment: and I see rows length 0 but insertid much more.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is be sure that you are opening the DB in or after deviceready has fired.

If you are doing it before deviceready the window.openDatabase will succeed but the $cordovaSQLite.openDB will likely fail. Wrapped with ionicPlatform ready everytimes you want to run the sqlite.

```
.controller('salesCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$cordovaSQLite', '$ionicPlatform', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform) {

      $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
         var db=null;

          if (window.cordova) {
             db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "pos.db" }); //device
             console.log("not in browser");
          } else{
             db = window.openDatabase("pos.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
             console.log("browser");
          }
           $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,firstname text  NOT NULL,lastname text  NOT NULL)");
       }); 

       $scope.insert=function(){
           $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
             var query="INSERT into items(firstname,lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
             $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,["name1","name2"]).then(function(result){

                            console.log(result.rows);
                        },function(error){
                                console.log(error);
                        });
              }
           });
        }

    }])
```

Comment: Your code shows error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of null

Comment: Try added location parameter to $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "pos.db" , location: "default"});