# Cannot read property 'transaction' of null ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new to ionic 1 development. I am trying to display data that I have inserted into my SQLite table. And I want to see them in chrome console. But, I am getting the below error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of null
    at Object.execute (ng-cordova.min.js:9)
    at ChildScope.$scope.insert (controllers.js:22)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), <anonymous>:4:209)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
```

And here's the snippet of my controller code. I have a separate js file for controllers.

```
.controller('salesCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$cordovaSQLite', '$ionicPlatform',
    function ($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform) {

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

            var db = null;

            if (window.cordova) {
                db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "pos.db" }); //device
                console.log("not in browser");
            } else{
                db = window.openDatabase("pos.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
                console.log("browser");
            }
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,firstname text  NOT NULL,lastname text  NOT NULL)");
        });

        $scope.insert = function(){
            var query="INSERT into items(firstname,lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,["name1","name2"]).then(function(result){
                console.log(result.rows);
            },function(error){
                console.log(error);

            }); 

        }


}])
```

And these are my installed cordova plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.6 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.5 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 1.5.3 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: Hi m8, still waiting for you input here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747576/cant-insert-data-in-sqlite-table-in-ionic-1

Comment: Isnt it the same question?

Comment: That question didn't showing any error. But, this time after I am having an error. @lin